# Rundeck Timestamp

Tags: rundeck

I have an issue with timestamp on rundeck, my machine hosting the application is in Europe/Paris timezone and CEST time but in Rundeck the timestamp displays in UTC.

So all the jobs are two hours late...

After reading many posts about this topic, tried to add this option in the profile configuration file but without success:

```
RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris"
```

Have you ever had this issue? Can you please help me?

Thanks, BR.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the Rundeck service.
2. If you're using a Debian/Ubuntu-based instance create the `/etc/default/rundeckd` file. If you're using a Redhat/CentOS/Rocky-based instance create the `/etc/sysconfig/rundeckd` file.

The `rundeckd` file must contain the following content:

```
RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris"
```

3. Save the file and then, Start the Rundeck instance.

You can test on two different timezones: [Paris](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hltaY.jpg) and [Santiago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMzrL.jpg) (`America/Santiago`).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your feedback i tested but the timestamp on the rundeck instance System > System Report is still in UTC...

Comment: That inconsistency was reported here https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6582 (it's a part of that report) can you add your use case there?